# How do I create a link in my user profile description?

Tags: support, users, user-interface

I am trying to create a link in my user profile description to the company where I work.  I have seen other users with links in their descriptions (Jon Skeet), but can't get it to work.  The 'basic HTML allowed' description says I can use `<a>`, but the tag gets stripped out when saved.

I have also tried the markdown way with `[My Link](http://www.google.com)` but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the `<a>` tags in my own profile, which works just fine:

```
<a href="http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/">CSVfix</a>
```

Comment: Ha. wow. Single vs double quotes matter.  With single quotes the link is stripped out.  Thanks.

Comment: @Brian: interesting. I can only assume the anti-XSS mechanism isn't robust enough to recognize single-quote HTML

Comment: Ugh. Aren't single quotes legal in HTML?

Comment: @Ether: yes, they are legal. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273354/html-single-quotes-a-problem

Comment: Currently, regular markdown works fine for links – but links in the "About" section of a user's site profile currently won't be rendered if that user doesn't have the [remove new user restrictions](/help/privileges/new-user) privilege on that site (granted at 10 rep).